# Discord Authorize Application

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make a bot in Python which can automatically set up Servers for you. I know how to do everything with the bot except the part, where the Bot automatically adds you.

How can I authorize the application to allow it to add me to servers and how do I make it add me to a server afterwards?

Edit: I tried https://github.com/discord/discord-oauth2-example but that didn't work because of an invalid redirect URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about that, but I have a simple script that creates a guild, then creates an invite link and invites you to the guild that's been created.

All you have to do afterwards is "!create Guild_Name"

Here's the code;

```py
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx, *, name):
    guild = await bot.create_guild(name=name)
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('welcome')
    invite_link = await channel.create_invite()
    await ctx.send(f"Succesfully created **{guild.name}**. (ID: {guild.id})\n"
        f"{invite_link}")
```